Estoy trabajando en una app android pero tengo el error de "Unknown Fragment" en mi layout del main activity
Estoy trabajando en una aplicacion en android studio con Kotlin para poder mostrar un mapa utilizando google maps, tengo mi api key funcionando y esta bien configurada, he seguido varios tutoriales pero todos me llevan al mismo error de "unknown fragment" he cambiado la forma de mostrar el fragment pero aun asi tengo el mismo error y es la unica parte que me detiene la aplicacion, probe iniciar una activity antes pero aun asi me cierra la aplicacion al ejecutarla.
A continuacion muestro el codigo de mis archivos que estoy trabajando en el desarrollo de la app.
Este es el codigo de mi MainActivity.kt
package com.brujula

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private var map:GoogleMap? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        map = googleMap
    }

}

Luego este es mi XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Finalmente este es mi gradle
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.brujula"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.brujula"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)

    //Map
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:19.0.0")

    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)

    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}

He intentado revisar la documentacion pero aun asi implementando
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>

Me sigue arrojando el mismo error de Unknown fragments

Si alguien sabe como poder resolver este problema del fragment seria de gran ayuda u otra forma de importar/cargar un mapa de google maps para utilizarlo en mi activity.
Se agradece todo comentario.

Por favor comparte tu código con formateo y no como imágenes.

Como ya comenta @Synay, conviene que pongas el código como texto, no capturas de imagen. Por otra parte, lee los mensajes de error. Para agregar fragmentos vía XML debes usar FragmentContainerView. Para más detalles considera leer la documentación sobre cómo agregar un fragmento por medio de XML.

Listo @A.Cedano ahi pude dejarlo con el codigo.

Listo @Synay espero les sirva.


Pude encontrar la falla era un error en otro apartado y el error de fragment simplemente lo suprimi en el studio.
Gracias igualmente

Entonces qué hiciste para solucionar el problema? Puede que le sirva a alguien más
